# Locating program positions on screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

If I open notepad.exe from a C++ program using CreateProcess(), is it possible to find the location of that notepad window which has started? I want to find its X and Y positions on screen.

Code: (Improved by suggestions) // Works

```
    Procces = CreateProcess(
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe",
    "-l D:\\Testing.txt",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000);

    HWND hwndNotePad = FindWindow(NULL, "Testing.txt - Notepad");
    RECT r;
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hwndNotePad) {

        GetWindowRect(hwndNotePad, &r);

        cout << r.bottom << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Should we assume this is Windows API?

Comment: Yes I am learning API now.

Comment: There are a number of issues, that you were likely aware of, but didn't really solve: You can only query a window's position after that window has been fully created. Your call to `WaitForSingleObject` however, doesn't do what you think. A process handle gets signaled when the process terminates. You should rather call [`WaitForInputIdle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx), which does precisely what you need.

Comment: The second parameter of `CreateProcess` should be writeable. Your code does not adhere to that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
HWND hwndNotePad = FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
RECT r;
if (NULL != hwndNotePad) {
    GetWindowRect(hwndNotePad, &r);
}
```

If you don't know the exact name, you can use `EnumWindows`. This is off the top of my head, so there might be errors:

```
main()
{
    //// .....
    HWND hwndNotePad = NULL;    // Store the result here
    EnumWindows(enumProc, (LPARAM)(&hwndNotePad);  // Check all windows
    if (NULL != hwndNotePad) {
        // Window found
        RECT r;
        GetWindowRect(hwndNotePad, &r);
    }
    //// ......
}

BOOL CALLBACK enumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Get title bar text
    char winTitle[256];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, winTitle, 256);
    if (NULL != strstr(winTitle, "Notepad")) {  // Check for match
        HWND *match = (HWND *)lParam;
        *match = hwnd;                  // Save result
        return FALSE;                   // No need to keep checking
    }
    else {
         return TRUE;          // No match. Keep checking
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I just tried this and I don't really now if its work I mean it does that stuff and then I try to cout << &r << endl; I get 0x28fdc0

Comment: Rect is a struct: `cout << r.left`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh ok but now then I do r.left I get 0 then r.right 2686868. What is it?

Comment: Not sure. What about top and bottom?

Comment: Top - 4668744 Bottom - 4258897. I've tried to change Notepad to something else and still it gives same coordinates or whatever it is, so my best guess is that it fails to find program. I added code to next to question maybe it'll help.

Comment: The text in quotes in the FindWindow call has to match exactly the text in the window's title bar. Also, I just checked and FindWindow returns NULL on failure. Will update answer

Comment: I just changed text to "Testing.txt - Notepad" and it looks like it works, but how to do exactly the same without knowing exactly title?

Comment: A more robust solution would probably call [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx) in the enumeration callback instead of comparing the window title. The window title may be subject to localization; the window class usually isn't. Unicode doesn't hurt either.

Comment: A more robust approach is to use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` inside of the enumeration and compare the thread/process IDs of each window to the IDs that `CreateProcess()` returns.  Then you don't have to look at the window title/name strings at all.